# simple math formula to code interpretation

Tags: c++, math, 3d

Im making a shader from a technical paper. But I ran into this formula. Which is hard to understand.
H=H-2(H,U)U
where H and U are vectors (x,y,z).
what operation means a(H,U) my understanding is something like:
H=H-(2*(H*U)*U);
But doing this, give me odd results.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `2(H.U)U` __probably__ means `2*(H dot product U)*U`. At least I would think that's a dot, not a comma, in that particular context.

Comment: I've rarely seen the notation (a,b) for the dot product. <a,b> is common tho. Anyway it is 99% a dot product, since that looks like the formula to reflect a vector H over a plane with normal U

Comment: yep its a dot product thanks a lot!

Comment: This question is off-topic; it is about understanding mathematical notation, not about programming.